# GCP Cloud Workflow region issue with Bigquery invocation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-workflows

I am running a Cloud Workflow which:

1. Initiates by GCS bucket CSV file load, where bucket region is EU Multiregion
2. Reads the CSV file using a Bigquery external table query, where the BQ dataset is EU Multiregion
3. Loads the file details into a BQ table in the same dataset which is in EU multiregion
4. All the above steps are in same project
5. The cloud workflow is located in europe-west1, as in CW we have to select specific region

Issue is in step 2, where in when the external file read query is initiated by cloud workflow I receive following error:

> Not found: Dataset 'project':'dataset' was not found in location europe-west1.

From what I understand as the bucket and dataset are multi-region EU, they should be able to initiate from workflow. Also error can be replicated, if you have a dataset\table in EU, and update the bigquery ->query settings ->Data location to specific location like europe-west1 from default, and query the table.  The same error will be thrown.

what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

@YunZhang PFA code - Cloud Workflow Region - europe-west4
Dataset region - EU
Cloud bucket region - eu (multiple regions in European Union)

````
main:
  params: [args]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - project_id: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
          - dataset_id: "<dataset>"
          - table_id: "<table>"
          - createDisposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
          - writeDisposition: "WRITE_APPEND"
          - query: "SELECT * FROM  `sourceproject.sourcedataset.viewreadingcsv`"
    - logInit:
          call: sys.log
          args:
            text: Starting BQ data load 
            severity: INFO          
    - startBQLoad:
          call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
          args:
            projectId: ${project_id}
            body:
                configuration:
                    query:
                        query: ${query}
                        destinationTable:
                            projectId: ${project_id}
                            datasetId: ${dataset_id}
                            tableId: ${table_id}
                        create_disposition: ${createDisposition}
                        write_disposition: ${writeDisposition}
                        useLegacySql: false```
````

Comment: It feels unexpected. Could you share the code how you send the query in the step 2?

Comment: Also, could you try simple query like `select * from <a_table_in_an_eu_dataset>`  works for you?

Comment: @YunZhang PFA code -

Comment: BigQuery itself always do region routing by default. I suspect  Cloud Workflow added some "region" to the request. To help confirm, could you try if simple query like select * from <a_table_in_an_eu_dataset> works for you?

Comment: @YunZhang Exeuted as instructed for a dataset in EU. Following error `Not found: Dataset projectName:DatasetName` was not found in location europe-west1`.  Note my observation on replicating the issue in original description.

Comment: Hi @RaptorX, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).